# MS Access 2010 Increase Available CPU

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I remember having done this on my XP machine, but my company just switched to Windows 7 (we're nothing if not timely) and now MS Access is running at 25% CPU when running large queries. I remember changing some registry setting that allowed me to peg it at 75%, which drastically cut the run time.

Anyone have an idea how to do this? I can't find/remember how to do it.